# create a web gui local with python?

Tags: python, user-interface, web, file-upload

I have a django app that takes a file, do some processing, and output a file (PDF report) to the user.
One of my clients wants to host this app locally.
Can I create a web interface which is HTML, CSS, JS based, locally (without a running web server dependency)?

Basically I just need a python program which will open a window with simple HTML-alike form, with a file upload, which will be processed by the same code which is currently in my django view. Then save/prompt the user to download a file (or just save it to its disk since it's a program).

I've checked `py2exe` which seems to fit, since the client won't necessarily have python installed.

I don't know how to create UI which is not web-based, so I'm asking for some pointers..

Comment: So you don't want the client to run a local host webserver?

Comment: If it was easy then ok, but to tell my client to run apache, or any other program and then open its browser on localhost, seems too much for normal people